# XMLHttpRequest POST giving error for media files

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am using below code to post data with ajax

```
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
oXHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
oXHR.open('POST', 'client/uploadvideo');
oXHR.send(vFD);
```

It is sending txt files but for other like .mp4 file its not working

Comment: It's not working is not very helpful. Was there an error message? Did you look at the Network request tab of your browser?

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Why is this tagged with jQuery, there's no jQuery here

Comment: So what is `vFD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` parameters, That required to be set on php.ini.

The error was not mentioning above need to be modified, So at first not understood what was the issue.

Answering this bcause might helpful to anybody